# gsutil rsync provide key at runtime

Tags: gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

I am currently extending the functionality of a file transfer application to include Google Cloud synchronizations, however I'm running into an issue. In the backend, we are merely running **gsutil rsync** commands on a linux server.

The users of the application will need to sync to different Google Cloud repositories/buckets, and I'd like to be able to tell the command which credentials/key file to use per sync job. For example, gsutil rsync "/source/path" "gs://destination-bucket" --key "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/config/rss.key"

The AWS CLI has sync profiles that can be specified at runtime (eg, aws s3 sync "/source/path" "s3://destination-bucket" --profile sync_profile_1), but I can't seem to find anything similar with Google Cloud's CLI.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gsutil` CLI uses Boto configs to load entire configuration files -- [see these docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil). You can tell gsutil to load additional Boto configs (i.e. to load several project- or key-specific settings) using the environment variables mentioned in the docs, or you can override individual config options using the top-level `-o` flag, [as shown here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/GlobalCommandLineOptions).

You'll probably want to override the `Credentials:gs_service_key_file` option. If you're not using a JSON keyfile, you'll also need to override the other options that start with `gs_service_`, as mentioned [in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config#configuring-service-account-credentials) for `gsutil config -e`.